# Unable to Send Json parameter as part of GET Request in Jemeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter to load test with 100 users

This is a REST Call using GET

As part of my request i am sending 3 parameters

1. ordersplitjson
2. customer_id
3. homedelivery

The ordersplitjson parameter is a JSON Value (somewhat big)

This is the request , captured from the browser and the same works when pasted in the browser directly

```
http:/localhost:8080/OMS/oms1/orderinsertservice?ordersplitjson={"highPriceVendor":"VC4%20Raj","vendors":{"T1":[{"item_ids_":"194","contact_phone_no_":"9876543210","name":"VC4%20Raj","contact_address":"Kukatpally,%20Hyderabad","leaf":[{"contact_phone_no":"9876543210","SurCharges":"50","vendorname":"VC4%20Raj","count":"0","contact_email":"rajk@gmail.com","discount_div":"10Rs","itemid":"194","strikeprice_cutoff":"110","name":"Popcorn%20Regular%20%20%20300%20ML%20Fountain%20Apple","quantity":"1","contact_address":"Kukatpally,%20Hyderabad","date_time":"18:10:19","email_id":"raj@hmail.com","toppings":[],"screen":"SCR-3","seat_num":"D12","customer_name":"Ganesh","image":"images/icon-print.png","contact_person":"Kiran","item_description":"Item%20description","vendor_id":"9","crusts":[],"Vat":"70","customer_mobil":"9090987878","price":"100","mobile_number":"1234567898","ServicesCharges":"50","orderid":"14101519"}],"vendor_id":"9"}]}}&customer_id=22&homedelivery=Yes
```

But under Jmeter , i am always getting error

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 64:
```

These are my screen shots

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Could anybody please help me how to resolve this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTTP Sampler Settings & HTTP Header settings should be same as the attached pictures below

[image: HTTP Sampler]

[image: HTTP Header]

Hope this will help.